# How to take an action before keyboard shows up?

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard

I added a listener for my keyboard so I could do something when it shows up,
first I tried `keyboardDidShow` and it worked, but I wanted my function to be triggered before keyboard shows up, so according to the [react native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard) I changed it to `keyboardWillShow`. Now it doesn't work at all!

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        'keyboardWillShow',
        ()=> this.setState({keyboard_open: true})
    );
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK. As you can see in the docs,

> `keyboardWillShow` as well as `keyboardWillHide` are generally not
>   available on Android since there is no native corresponding event.

So if you're testing on an Android device, it is not supported but it should work fine on iOS devices.

Comment: is there any workaround so I can achieve the same result on android?

Comment: @BlueTurtle I don't think so. They have only implemented DidShow on Android.